# Where to add a c-wire on my Goodman furnace?

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I'm looking to upgrade my old thermostat and need to run a c-wire. Where would be the best place to tap into?[image][image]

Comment: If there's a wiring diagram on the inside of the cover please edit a photo of that into your question.

Comment: Is there a spare wire in the thermostat wiring to use as a C wire, or are you running a new thermostat cable for this?

Answer (score 1):

### Connect it to the junction of the fat blue wire and the skinny white wire

We know the fat blue wire in the foreground is a C wire, as it's currently returning current from the air conditioner compressor contactor (via chassis ground, which is odd, but it's what the wiring diagram on this unit calls out) already.  The easiest place to splice into it is at the existing wirenut junction, although it appears you may have to hunt around for a spare wire in your existing cable if one is present but not visible, or pull a new thermostat cable if your existing one has no spare wires in it.

Comment: Wish all questions could be answered so poetically :)

Answer (score 0):

> Where would be the best place to tap into?

whatever side of the transformer goes to Rh or Rc on the thermostat, the C (common) is the other side of the transformer.  From that other side of the transformer or tapping off the wire from that other side of transformer goes to the C terminal of your new thermostat.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to tap into the blue wire coming off the secondary side of the 24v transformer. You can see the transformer in your first picture, it has the white and black wires going into the top and the blue and red wires going into the bottom. You want to tap into the blue wire. Now you may have noticed the blue wire also goes to ground... **Do not take a short cut and attach your c wire to ground.**  You can't use ground to carry load, so splice into the blue wire. good luck.

Comment: Looks like there's a blue wire already sharing the ground screw left of the transformer, wire-nutted to one of the solid low voltage wires, I'd guess that's the wiring that goes to the contactor in the condenser. That should be moved.

Comment: It can stay as is.

Comment: Questions.  1) The 24V common here is bonded to ground.  I haven't seen that before.  I can't think why you would or would not want to do that.  It's done in some electronics applications to reduce noise on the low voltage side.  But here, it seems unimportant.  Is there anything to this?  2) I think you're saying that if you don't have a C wire, don't exploit this odd bonding situation by running your thermostat C terminal to the nearest available ground source.  Is that what you mean?  Seems wise but I can't actually think why.  The usual reasons of using ground as a "current path" ?